# Why is the middle third Cantor set written as this?

Tags: general-topology

My first question is, is the middle third Cantor set the same as the Cantor set? I've never heard it called the middle third Cantor set.

Secondly, why is this true:

"I’m going to assume that *Cantor set* here refers to the standard middle-thirds Cantor set $C$ described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set). It can be described as the set of real numbers in $[0,1]$ having ternary expansions using only the digits $0$ and $2$, i.e., real numbers of the form $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{3^n},$$ where each $a_n$ is either $0$ or $2$. "

I'm not truly understanding why it would be 0 or 2 for $a_n$. I understand that the numbers from [0,1] can be written in ternary as 0,1, or 2. I don't understand why the "1" is taken out. Is it because we take the middle third out every time and we lose anything that can be written in ternary as "1"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called the middle-thirds Cantor set because in general you can construct a class of sets with similar properties using a similar but scaled construction. For example, you can start with $[0,1]$, remove an interval of length $\frac{1}{2}$ from the center. Then you have $2$ intervals of length $\frac{1}{4}$, remove an interval of length $\frac{1}{8}$ from the center. Inductively, at each step you have a disjoint union of intervals of length $l$ remaining in your set, and you remove an interval of length $l/2$ from each interval. This set, which we might call the Cantor "middle-halves" set, has many of the same properties of the Cantor middle-thirds set. From this you can imagine constructing the "middle-fourths" set and many other Cantor-type sets. The middle-thirds set is sort of standard because it's the easiest Cantor-type set to construct (mainly it's easy to figure out the lengths of the intervals at each step).

The reason for the ternary expansion is precisely as you stated, the middle-thirds construction removes any numbers with *absolutely necessary* $1$-s in the ternary expansion. You should check this for yourself for a few cases: for example, check if $0.1abcd...$ (ternary) can be in the middle-thirds set, then $0.01abcd...$, $0.21abcd...$, and so on. Then you'll see why the Cantor set construction removes them. This excludes cases like $1/3$, which lies in the Cantor set and has ternary expansion $0.1000...$, because it can also be written $0.0222...$ .

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't 0.01 = 1/9 in our normal numerical system, and isn't that left when you take away the first middle third?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely my point.

Comment: But if 1/9 is left doesn't that mean our summation includes ternary values with 1 in them?

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem is that ternary expansions are not unique. $1/9$ can be written as $0.01000...$, but it can also be written as $0.00222...$. (Like how $1 = 0.999...$.) The convention is to write the ternary expansion with only $0$-s and $2$-s *if possible*, and throw out numbers that require a $1$ no matter what you do. Notice that you also keep $1/3$ (and in general lots of $k/3^n$-s) by the middle-thirds construction (they lie at the endpoints of intervals you don't delete), but the ones you keep can all be written without $1$-s.

Comment: I'm not really sure how you can write it as 0.00222...., do you mind explaining this? Also, but if 1/9 is equal to both 0.002222 and 0.01000 in ternary, don't we still keep it in our set? Can you give an example of something we don't keep which isn't of the form $k/3^n$?

Comment: It's like how in base $10$, $1 = 0.999...$. The base $3$ series for $0.0222...$ is $2/3^2 + 2/3^3 + 2/3^4 + ... = (2/9)\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1/3^k = (2/9)[1/(1-1/3)] = 1/3$. Since we can write $1/3$ without any $1$-s if we choose to, we keep it in our set; same deal with $1/9$. Things we don't keep of the form $k/3^n$ are something like $4/9$ and $5/9$, which get removed at the first step. You can't write those in ternary without $0.1$ to start off.

Comment: I'm thankful for your help but I still do not follow. I just saw your edit, let me think on this.

Comment: So let me get this straight. When we take away the middle 1/3 after each iteration, we lose any value that can be written in ternary with the number "1" in its base 3 form. However, we do not lose the numbers which have "1" in their base 3 form if it is an endpoint, which is equivlant to saying it is of the form $1/3^n$, due to the possibility to write it in the form of "2"s and not "1's?

Comment: Not quite; for example, $2/3$ is an endpoint we keep as well (but of course $2/3 = 0.2000...$ so this is fine). We lose any values that *must have* $1$ in its ternary expansion, not the ones that merely *can be written* with $1$. The numbers $1/3^n$ are examples of numbers that *can be written* with $1$ in ternary, but they don't *have to be written* with $1$. You can always do $0.000....0222...$ (0-s until the $n+1$-th ternary place) for these instead of $0.000...01000...$ ($0$-s until the $n$-th ternary place). Therefore we keep all $1/3^n$, though this doesn't exhaust the list of endpoints.

Comment: Wouldn't 2/3 be 2.1 in ternary?

Comment: $2.1 = 2 + 1/3^1 = 7/3$ in ternary. $2/3 = 0 + 2/3^1 = 0.2$. Maybe your confusion is just due to not being familiar with numbers in different bases?

Comment: That probably has a lot to do with it. If you could be so kind to just explain how you got .2 for 2/3 it would solve a lot of my issues.

Comment: Wait, is it 0.2 because 2/3 = 2(0.1) = 0.2? Is this true for any numerator? For example 5/3 = 5 (0.1) = 0.5? Or 5/27 = 5(0.001)=0.005? I think my 5/27 example is wrong.

Comment: In base $3$, any number in $[0,1]$ can be written in the form $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k/3^k$, with $a_k$ $0$, $1$, or $2$. One sometimes writes this number in the form $0.a_1a_2a_3...$. Since $2/3 = 0 + 2/3^1 + 0 + 0 + ...$, $a_k = 0$ for $k\neq 1$ and $a_1 = 2$, so $2/3 = 0.a_1000... = 0.2$. Your comment above is almost correct, you need to remember that in ternary $0.5$ doesn't make sense. You forgot to carry the $5$, $5/3 = 5(0.1) = 3(0.1) + 2(0.1) = 1 + 0.2 = 1.2$.

Comment: So for 5/3, it would be 5(0.1) but since 5 can be written as 3+2 = 5, we have 3(0.1) + 2(0.1), but since ternary only includes (0,1,2) and 3 in ternary is 1, we have 3=1 (ternary) and since 2 in ternary is just 2 (because 2 times 1 gives 2), we have 1+ 2(0.2) = 1.2 in ternary. I'm a bit confused as to why 3(0.1) isn't 1(0.1) in ternary?

Comment: $3$ is not $1$ in ternary. $3 = 3(1) = 3(3^0) + 0 + 0 + ...$ in the ternary series expansion, so $3$ is $10$ in base $3$.

Comment: Oh so let me try this once more. So we have 5/3, we would have 5(0.1) = 3(0.1) + 2(0.1) = 10(0.1) + 2(0.1) = 1 + .2 = 1.2? Let me try 7/27 = 7(0.001) = 3(0.001) + 3(0.001) + 1(0.001) = 10(0.001) + 10(0.001) + 0.001 = 0.01 + 0.01 + 0.001 = .021?

Comment: Yes, that will work. It's much easier to work by expanding into fractions though. The "decimal" point notation is just a shorthand. If you understand the answer to the original question and you just want to know about ternary arithmetic, please ask a new question instead of carrying on in the comments.

Comment: I'm not very sure how to tell the difference between something that is strictly written with "1s" in the ternary form versus something that can be written with "1s" or "2s". But I understand that in the cantor middle third set, the process of repeatedly removing the middle 1/3 removes any number with the ternary form represented strictly with "1s" in it and keeps anything that can be written with 0 or 2 (including non-unique numbers such as 1/9 which can be written with both "1s" or "2s".

Answer (score 2):

You can build several "essentially" different cantor sets, some have Lebesgue measure 0, some have positive measure. For instance, take the unit interval, remove the "middle fifth" (take a linear function to the interval $[0, 5]$ and remove the preimage of the open $(2,3)$). On step 2, remove the "middle twenty-fifth" of each of the two remaining intervals, etc. At the end you will get a nowhere dense closed set with no isolated points (so, a Cantor set), but its measure will be strictly positive.

The standard Cantor is cbuild by removing one third of each interval at each step, and yes, it relates to the '1' digit in the ternary expansion of the number.

Answer (score 1):

First question: typically *the* Cantor set is the middle third Cantor set, while *a* Cantor set can be any of a number of similar sets, including variants that have positive measure.

Second question: essentially, yes. Being more precise, in the $i$th stage of the construction one removes all the remaining numbers whose ternary expansion has a $1$ in the $i$th place. Hence at the end of the construction, all the numbers have no $1$s in their ternary expansion.